# How can I change the input element in TextField element MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

**So I have TextField elements in my application and they seem to be a bit too big. I inspect it and in elements I see it has input element which has too big padding by default.**[image]

**My question is how can I modify the input element inside the TextField ? I haven't done much styling with MUI so I need help thanks.**

Comment: You can use `size="small"` prop on `TextField`. if you could share your code then we can inspect and help more properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `sx` prop to apply custom styling to the element rendered by MUI, Check more about `sx` prop [here](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/)

Example :

```
 <Box
  sx={{
    color: "success.dark",
    display: "inline",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    mx: 0.5,
    fontSize: 14,
  }}
>
  +18.77%
</Box>;
```

Comment: I know how to use sx prop this doesn't help me it modifies the TextField element. I need to modify the input inside the TextField element

Comment: You have to target the override class within the sx prop to customize one of classes inside the element, check the slider example over [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/)